# Why do space ships that have technology to travel faster than light have primitive controls using toggle switches and atari graphic displays?

Tags: star-wars, star-trek

I'm so sick of looking at every space ship in Star Wars that looks like it's about to fall apart but it has the technology to travel at warp speeds yet it has controls from the 50's using toggle switches and Atari pong graphics for their displays. Every ship has the technology to fold space time itself using virtually limitless amounts of energy to do so and yet it uses rockets and toggle switches!

I recently watched Netflix's Lost in Space which I loved. They had a super advanced robot that had nano technology but when it got in it's space ship had to manually push these giant pedals to get the ship to do anything. Common!!!!! So you're telling me they forgot to put WiFi in it?

Every technology in a culture maintains a certain relationship with itself. It's like if today we had to use carrier pigeons to communicate. Even that would be a much closer comparison. The level of tech that you would be at to fold space time and have access to zero point energy to be able to do that you would at least have quantum computers and store things on glass chips. The ship's computer would automatically connect telepathically to whatever intelligence was near it and had access. At the very lest they would wear glasses that projected onto the eye or some other tech.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Umm...  This is more of a rant than a real question.  You might be able to turn this into a question - why is retro technology used to depict futuristic spacecraft controls? - but if you keep the ranty bits you risk having this question downvoted and closed.  FWIW, I feel your pain, but this isn't the proper venue for the rant. :)

Comment: Why do cars nowadays still have steering wheels and pedals instead of cool airplane controls, if cars can drive themselves? Why do we still have phone numbers instead of just using leet handles? Heck why do we use cutlery if we could just inject nutrients in our bloodstream? Practicity is so *passé*, right?

Comment: Try "come on," not "common."

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a reasonable answer: Sometimes old scifi movies/tv shows were bad/inconsistent at anticipating technological advances (Star Trek for example, has antimatter powering warp drive -- that is plausible in the sense that this has the highest theoretical energy density of any substance but also apparently the ship lacks a network and Yeoman Janice Rand handed Kirk reports.)

Of course, humans could not control a ship moving faster than light by hand and, not in tight maneuvers -- I don't know if this has been addressed in later incarnations or novels -- but it would not be very interesting if humans were nor required to operate the ship. For the same reason, the computer is not AI -- they have AI in the STOS but it never works out, always some problem like the computer whose inventor used his *own* engrams to design its mind -- heck, any school kid today knows you don't use your *own* engrams, at least I hope they do. (I was asked that in a job interview last February and I said I sure wouldn't use my own.)

Anyway, some of the limitations in science fiction films (and even novels) are deliberate so humans remain integral to the story.

Answer (score 0):

The controls may be the lowest common denominator for various species to use them. They need to be large, simple to manipulate with various appendages and the displays have to be clear. Can't rely on things like colours that some races can't see, or diagrams that don't scan well for them.

This is not dissimilar to provisions for colour blind and disabled human users today.

Comment: not a crazy answer but bottom line is piloting a FTL spaceship would be nothing like piloting a fighter jet, for example.